# Pandas Data science Get mean age for the billionaires in top 2 industries

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a Forbes billionaire data set as below
[image]

and the first step is to find top 3 industries which has most billionaires. Which can easily be obtained from `value_counts` as below:

```
a = forbes_billionaire["Industries"].value_counts().head(3)
```

Output

```
Finance & Investments    296
Technology               237
Fashion & Retail         206
```

But the next question is somewhat tricky.
Compare the mean of net worth of billionaires from these top 3 industries
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Net Worth'].groupby(df['Industires']).mean().sort_values(ascending = False).head(3)
```

Comment: replace age with net worth if you want the mean age of the billionaires as your title says.

Comment: The maximum number of billionaires are in                                                         
Finance & Investments    296
Technology               237
Fashion & Retail         206

Comment: The maximum number of billionaires are in                                                         
Finance & Investments    296
Technology               237
Fashion & Retail         206                                                                                                              The question is to find the mean of billionaires from the top 3 industries                            Industries which has maximum billionaires
Technology          5.660338
Fashion & Retail    5.224272
Telecom             4.941379